# Android : Check 3G or Wifi network is ON or Available or not on android Device

Tags: android, networking, wifi, 3g

How to check that network is available or not on android device programmatically, which throws a message or toast message when we are trying to connect with a network such as Wifi & 3G.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

TO check whether network i.e 3G or WiFi is available or not we can use below methods to verify before starting our activities.

```
ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

//For 3G check
boolean is3g = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
            .isConnectedOrConnecting();
//For WiFi Check
boolean isWifi = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
            .isConnectedOrConnecting();

System.out.println(is3g + " net " + isWifi);

if (!is3g && !isWifi) 
{ 
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please make sure your Network Connection is ON ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} 
 else 
{ 
        " Your method what you want to do "
}
```

Hope this will help someone.

Comment: http://rahulbaradiaa.blogspot.in/2012/07/check-wifi-3g-availability-on-android.html u can get the information here too..

Comment: Nullpointer in     boolean is3g = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).isConnectedOrConnecting();

Comment: As @benoffi7 said, you have to test that manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.*) is not null before to call the isConnectedOrConnecting() method.

Comment: `getInfoNetwork(int)` is now deprecated. Just for the record (see [this StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32547006/connectivitymanager-getnetworkinfoint-deprecated) for an updated version).

Comment: getNetworkInfo() is depreciated now, because for example: in case, there are 2 cellular networks on device.

Answer (score 7):

```
final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
    this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi =
    connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

    final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile =
    connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

    if( wifi.isAvailable() && wifi.getDetailedState() == DetailedState.CONNECTED){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Wifi" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if( mobile.isAvailable() && mobile.getDetailedState() == DetailedState.CONNECTED ){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Mobile 3G " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
    {   
        Toast.makeText(this, "No Network " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

this code check if you are with wifi or 3g or nothing , in the case of wifi on but not connected to a net or 3g have signal problem it detect this details, with DetailedStates

Answer (score 6):

You can use this method to check whether your internet connection is **2G, 3G or 4G**:

```
public String getNetworkClass(Context context) {
    TelephonyManager mTelephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    int networkType = mTelephonyManager.getNetworkType();
    switch (networkType) {
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_IDEN:
            return "2G";
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP:
            return "3G";
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE:
            return "4G";
        default:
            return "Unknown";
    }
}
```

And using following method you can check if **internet is available or not**, and get whether you are accessing the internet via a **mobile network or WiFi**:

```
public String getNetworkType(Context context){
    String networkType = null;
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (activeNetwork != null) { // connected to the internet
        if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                networkType = "WiFi";
        } else if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
            networkType = "Mobile";
        }
    } else {
        // not connected to the internet
    }
    return networkType;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This work for me

```
NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();   
String name networkInfo.getTypeName();
```

Answer (score 3):

Rahul Baradia's answer includes `manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)` and it's deprecated.

Below is an improved solution for the latest Android SDK.

```
ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        boolean is3gEnabled = false;
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Network[] networks = connManager.getAllNetworks();
            for(Network network: networks)
            {
                NetworkInfo info = connManager.getNetworkInfo(network);
                if(info!=null) {
                    if (info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                        is3gEnabled = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NetworkInfo mMobile = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
            if(mMobile!=null)
                is3gEnabled = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code as **NetworkChecker.java** & **reuse it in your code**:

```
package das.soumyadip.util;

import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class NetworkChecker {
    private final static String TAG = "NwtworkChecker";

    public static boolean isNetworkConnected(
            final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager) {
        boolean val = false;

        Log.d(TAG, "Checking for Mobile Internet Network");
        final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connectivityManager
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
        if (mobile.isAvailable() && mobile.isConnected()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Found Mobile Internet Network");
            val = true;
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Mobile Internet Network not Found");
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Checking for WI-FI Network");
        final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connectivityManager
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        if (wifi.isAvailable() && wifi.isConnected()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Found WI-FI Network");
            val = true;
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "WI-FI Network not Found");
        }

        return val;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the switched off wifi (or 3G) is an error (Log.e(TAG, "WI-FI Network not Found")) 0_0? It is a valid case for a phone and for many apps that can do work (maybe part of it) without it.

Why so many logging in such utility and not mission-critical code?

Answer (score 1):

```
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ConnectivityManager connMgr =
                (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connectivityManager
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
        if (mobile.isAvailable() && mobile.isConnected()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Found Mobile Internet Network");
            val = true;
        }
        // Checks the user prefs and the network connection. Based on the result, decides
        // whether
        // to refresh the display or keep the current display.
        // If the userpref is Wi-Fi only, checks to see if the device has a Wi-Fi connection.
        if (WIFI.equals(sPref) && networkInfo != null
                && networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
            // If device has its Wi-Fi connection, sets refreshDisplay
            // to true. This causes the display to be refreshed when the user
            // returns to the app.
            refreshDisplay = true;
            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.wifi_connected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // If the setting is ANY network and there is a network connection
            // (which by process of elimination would be mobile), sets refreshDisplay to true.
        }

}
        else if (ANY.equals(sPref) && networkInfo != null) {
            refreshDisplay = true;

            // Otherwise, the app can't download content--either because there is no network
            // connection (mobile or Wi-Fi), or because the pref setting is WIFI, and there
            // is no Wi-Fi connection.
            // Sets refreshDisplay to false.
        } else {
            refreshDisplay = false;
            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.lost_connection, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use **ConnectivityManager Class** for any information related to network.

It also notifies applications when network **connectivity changes**. Get an instance  of this class by calling

**The primary responsibilities of this class are to:**

1. Monitor network connections (Wi-Fi, GPRS, UMTS, etc.)
2. Send broadcast intents when network connectivity changes
3. Attempt to "fail over" to another network when connectivity to a network
     is lost
4. Provide an API that allows applications to query the coarse-grained or fine-grained
     state of the available networks
5. Provide an API that allows applications to request and select networks for their data
     traffic

**GetNetworkInfo function** return status information about a particular network type.

This method requires the caller to hold the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

     /**
     * Checks the type of data connection that is currently available on the device.
     *
     * @return <code>ConnectivityManager.TYPE_*</code> as a type of internet connection on the
     *This method does not support multiple connected networks
     *             of the same type.
     * device. Returns -1 in case of error or none of
     * <code>ConnectivityManager.TYPE_*</code> is found.
     **/
```

--

```
public static int getDataConnectionType(Context ctx) {

        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        if (connectivityManager != null && connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) != null) {
            if (connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).isConnected()) {
                return ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE;
            } else if (connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnected()) {
                return ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI;
            } else
                return -1;
        } else
            return -1;
    }
```

Comment: this return only that connected to network type, not return the type that enabled by user.

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean isInternetAvailable(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (activeNetwork != null) { // connected to the internet
        if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
            // connected to wifi
            return true;

        } else if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
            // connected to the mobile provider's data plan
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        // not connected to the internet
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in none of the code above i see a check for whether getNetworkInfo() returned null, which happens according to the docs when the requested network type is not supported. this suggests that on devices without 3g the app will crash with null pointer exception.