# Android Check Wifi Connectivity Without Disconnecting 3G

Tags: android, mobile, wifi, connectivity

Currently investigating this area will update this post if / when i find anything out. Any extra brain power will be much appreciated on this.

similar but not duplicate thread - [Android : Check 3G or Wifi network is ON or Available or not on android Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11343249/android-check-3g-or-wifi-network-is-on-or-available-or-not-on-android-device)

Use case.

User walking along the road using 3G. When the background service sees that networks are available :

- Check if the Wifi network that we now see can be associated to.
- Check if the Wifi provides an active connection (do a test ping and look for expected results)
- Does the Wifi network need a Wispr Login.
- If it does perform our Wispr authentication logic.
- Then ONLY once we have got an active connection, switch the user off of 3G and onto that WiFi network.

Basically, can I send calls specifically using the WIFI device port whilst allowing the user to continue using 3G?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there might be a way - [Let WiFi and 3G connection work together by hacking ConnectivityService.java](http://mobisocial.stanford.edu/news/2011/03/let-wifi-and-3g-connection-work-together-by-hacking-connectivityservice-java/) - but looks nasty.

Could you enable both - check for wifi connectivity and then disconnect 3g /or wifi depending on the outcome?

Comment: THe link looks good, however I'd rather not have to reboot the whole device / much around with system classes. This will be an app on the play store so if I can do it from within the app would be good. Although on looking at the article in detail maybe unfeasible. Thanks for your response.