# Check whether mobile is using WIFI or Data/3G

Tags: android

Assuming that both WIFI and Data/3G are enabled on a device, how do I check if the user is currently using the internet over the wifi or the data plan assuming they are both enabled. So I don't need to check if they are enabled or disabled, I would like to detect which one is the user actually using.

I've been doing the following, is this the only solution?

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
if (WifiInfo.getDetailedStateOf(wifiInfo.getSupplicantState()) == NetworkInfo.DetailedState.CONNECTED) {
    String ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID();
}
```

Comment: Check this out (http://stackoverflow.com/a/11343250/833647)

Comment: @KenWolf very nice link

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android : Check 3G or Wifi network is ON or Available or not on android Device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11343249/android-check-3g-or-wifi-network-is-on-or-available-or-not-on-android-device)

Comment: Please if you have gotten an answer approve it?

Answer (score 30):

```
void chkStatus() {
    final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
    this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    if (wifi.isConnectedOrConnecting ()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Wifi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (mobile.isConnectedOrConnecting ()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Mobile 3G ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No Network ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is this downvote for please comment so I can work on my answers as far as I know I am very much correct

Comment: If it's already been answered, please link to the question rather than plagiarizing the answer. Certainly the answer is correct -- you copied it, after all. However, that just create duplicates on SO, making SO overall less usable.

Comment: Your answer is wrong. isAvailable() tells if network connectivity via wifi or mobile is possible, but don't tell if there is actual connection. You must check isConnectedOrConnecting() or just isConnected().

Comment: thanks for pointing this out, I will update my answer but I believe it solved the ARMAGEDDON's problem.

Comment: This solution is deprecated, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32547006/connectivitymanager-getnetworkinfoint-deprecated for the new solution

Comment: Can someone tell why they are using two variable for one condition. Don't you think it could be simply check with one variable like this way 
`android.net.NetworkInfo internet = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if( internet.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
            networkStatus = "wifi";
        }else if(internet.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE){
            networkStatus = "mobileData";
        }`

Comment: Both "mobile" and "wifi" variables can be null, so asking for "isConnectedOrConnecting()" could raise a NPException. Keeping that in mind this should be the accepted solution.

Comment: Hey this one helped , And how do we detect any changes, like user switch from wifi to mobile data, any Listers for this?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following method to check network status every time:

```
public static String checkNetworkStatus(final Context context) {

        String networkStatus = "";

        // Get connect mangaer
        final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)  
                context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        // check for wifi
        final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

        // check for mobile data
        final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

        if( wifi.isAvailable() ) {
            networkStatus = "wifi";
        } else if( mobile.isAvailable() ) {
            networkStatus = "mobileData";
        } else {
            networkStatus = "noNetwork";
        }

        return networkStatus;

}  // end checkNetworkStatus
```

//vKj

Answer (score 0):

```
 public boolean CheckConnectivity(final Context c) {
        ConnectivityManager mConnectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) c.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (mConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                && mConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                && mConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false; // make it false
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is to check if Internet is connected or not , It won't tell if you are connected with wifi or mobile data

Answer (score 0):

`getNetworkInfo` is a deprecated method.
I suggest to use `getActiveNetworkInfo`

Example

```
private String checkNetworkStatus(Context context) {

    String networkStatus = "";
    final ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if( manager.getActiveNetworkInfo().getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
        networkStatus = "wifi";
    } else if(manager.getActiveNetworkInfo().getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE){
        networkStatus = "mobileData";
    } else{
        networkStatus="noNetwork";
    }
    return networkStatus;
}
```

Comment: In your code both wifi and mobile objects have same value.

Comment: how did this get 3 upvotes? you're returning a value from the same `NetworkInfo` object.

Comment: `getActiveNetworkInfo` is now [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#getActiveNetworkInfo())