# When downloading data over WiFi, how do I know I am connected using Wifi

Tags: java, android, wifi, httpurlconnection, connectivity

Using `ConnectivityManager`, I can check if the user is connected to WiFi. If yes, my app begins downloading. After writing the data to local storage, I check again if the user is connected to WiFi. If not, I stop the downloading.

Now, what I want to know is.. **how do I ensure that the `HttpURLConnection` made is via WiFi ?**

Another feature is where the user is liberal about the downloads. user allows the app to download either via WiFi or via network.

Assume a scenario where the user has WiFi turned on. The app checks if WiFi is available and begins downloading. Later, user switches off WiFi or moves out of the signal range. **What happens to the connection then? Does it switch over to using network?**

Also, **how do I ensure that the `HttpURLConnection` is made via network?**

*All in all, I just need to avoid a nasty situation where the user ends up spending a lot of money accidentally over download. This is not a very critical app, I am doing this just for practice*

Comment: Isn't this a device setting? Wifi preferred vs 3G preferred?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I do not know. I am a novice. Read the last line of the question. Suggestions welcome.

Comment: Here's something: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11343249/android-check-3g-or-wifi-network-is-on-or-available-or-not-on-android-device

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I know that. But when both network is available and WiFi is connected, what is the connection made using ? Or I should not bother about it ?

Comment: Wifi gets precedence over any cellular network.

Answer (score 1):

```
ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo info = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
```

More information can be extracted from `NetworkInfo`. Just check [this reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html).

You'll need this permission:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

Complementing: I am not sure if it's an Android default or a device configuration, but whenever there is an established wifi connection, 3G is automatically disabled. I tested in a few devices and all of them have this behavior.